# Firebase on Android: How to check client bandwidth used?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, network-traffic

I have a large number of users who are particular about cellular data use. I want to do a thorough evaluation of how much bandwidth is consumed by Firebase database in a typical session in my app on the client side.

Is there any way to track Firebase network usage? I have set logging level to debug and can see some connection related messages, but I'd really like to analyze the actual network usage in bytes.

I have already rolled out Firebase on a paid plan, and facing a huge bandwidth bill!

***Update:***
I created a test app with only Firebase (and no other network component), and used Android Device Monitor - Network Statistics.

```
// calling this 10 times generated 16 KB traffic
// size of json actually stored on server was 423 bytes total under ref key
ref.push().setValue(System.currentTimeMillis());

// later, calling this 10 times generated 20 KB traffic
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);
```

Comment: In a test environment the [Android Studio Network Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-network.html) gives a high-level view of network usage.  It's not the detailed byte counts you're looking for but might be helpful.